# show $f(z)=Az^2+Bz+C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ be an entire function where $z=x+iy$.

Suppose there exist real-valued differentiable functions $\phi(x)$ and $\psi (y)$ s.t. $u(x,y)=\phi(x)+\psi(y) \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.

Show there exist $A\in\mathbb{R}$ and $B,C\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=Az^2+Bz+C$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

I have no idea at all on how to start... Any hint?

Comment: Use the Cauchy-Riemann equations, and the fact that the real and imaginary parts of holomorphic functions are harmonic to determine the possible shapes of $\phi$ and $\psi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. According to Cauchy-Riemann
$$
\varphi'(x)=u_x=v_y.
$$
Thus
$$
v(x,y)=\varphi'(x)y+c_1(x).
$$
Also,
$$
\psi'(y)=u_y=-v_x=-\varphi''(x)y-c_1'(x).
$$
Thus $\phi''=c_2$ and $c_1(x)=ax+b$.